# Invoke a method (not a function) using a string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Note to dup finders: please feel free to mark this as a dup if the dup shows how to solve with classes and methods, not just functions.

I'm building a command line tool that solicits string input from the user then tries to invoke a class with matching methods and params. How do I call so that this is defined?

I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }
  myMethod(param) {
    console.log(param, this.foo);  // this is undefined, based on how I invoke it
  }
}
```

I'd like to do this, once I get the user input...

```
let userInputMethod = 'myMethod';
let userInputParam = 'param';

const myInstance = new MyClass();
const method = myInstance[userInputMethod];
method(userInputParam);  // error, because I need somehow to set the context of this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` context is lost, you need to `bind` it.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }
  myMethod(param) {
    console.log(param, this.foo);
  }
}

let userInputMethod = 'myMethod';
let userInputParam = 'param';

const myInstance = new MyClass();
const method = myInstance[userInputMethod].bind(myInstance); // bind
method(userInputParam);
```

Or you could use arrow functions.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }
  myMethod = (param) => {
    console.log(param, this.foo);
  }
}

let userInputMethod = 'myMethod';
let userInputParam = 'param';

const myInstance = new MyClass();
const method = myInstance[userInputMethod]
method(userInputParam);
```

Comment: Very similar to my answer, posted some minutes later after mine :)

btw you shouldn't use arrow functions like that but in the constructor.

Comment: Actually, @EliazBobadilla, I saw both answers, and preferred this one because of the working snippet. (I hope you didn't downvote on this basis).

Answer (score 1):

You could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it

```js
let userInputMethod = 'myMethod';
let userInputParam = 'param';

const myInstance = new MyClass();
const method = myInstance[userInputMethod].bind(myInstance)
method(userInputParam);
```

But at that point why not use plain objects?

```js
// foo.js
const foo = "bar";

const hey = {
  myMethod(param) {
    console.log(param, foo);
  },
};
```

```js
//main.js
let userInputMethod = 'myMethod';
let userInputParam = 'param';

const method = hey[userInputMethod];
method(userInputParam);
```

If you need your class to receive data you can use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) like this

```js
function makeInstance({ foo }) {
  return {
    myMethod(param) {
      console.log(param, foo);
    },
  };
}
```